# How to remove an error regarding increment of a while loop

Tags: perl

I am using the following Perl script to write out a shell script:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$incr=0.1;
$dist=5.1;

my $filename = 'job-1.sh';

open (my $BATCHFILE, '>', "$filename");

while ($dist <= 15) {
    print $BATCHFILE
"
YOYO -O -i min_mdin.$dist
";
   
    $dist += $incr;
}

close ($BATCHFILE);
```

The job-1.sh file should contain the following lines:

```sh
YOYO -O -i min_mdin.5.1
YOYO -O -i min_mdin.5.2
……
YOYO -O -i min_mdin.15
```

However, some files are printed as follows:

```sh
YOYO -O -i min_mdin.6.49999999999999

YOYO -O -i min_mdin.6.59999999999999
```

This problem occurs only when the increment is 0.1. An increment of 0.2 or 0.25 do not give this error.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's happening:

https://floating-point-gui.de

As a quick fix try something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$incr=1;
$dist=51;

while ($dist <= 150)
{
    print $dist/10 . "\n";
    $dist += $incr;
}
```

Or this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

$incr = 0.1;
$dist = 5.1;

while ($dist <= 15)
{
    print sprintf("%.2f",$dist) . "\n";
    $dist = $dist + $incr;
}
```